# Как сервер обрабатывает JWT токены?

Tags: jwt

Я пишу систему авторизации в своём пэт-проекте и не могу понять. Как сервер обрабатывает JWT токены, которые присылает клиент? Хранит ли он их где-то в базе данных? Или когда сервер присылает запрос с токеном, он декодирует его, потом делает запрос в бд, вытягивает логин и пароль из базы данных и сравнивает их? Объясните, добрые люди

Comment: Не хранит и не делает никаких запросов, а просто проверяет подлинность токена с помощью подписи

Comment: в jwt проверка по базе не нужна

Comment: Получается, что сервер проверяет только секретный ключ?

Comment: @Ilya не проверяет секретный ключ. Сервер, выпустивший токен, подписывает его закрытым ключом. Сервер, проверяющий токен, проверяет подлинность с помощью публичного ключа выпускающего сервера. В самом токене обычно находится id пользователя, которые не надо запрашивать из бд